# Sort-Object having no effect on Get-EventLog

Tags: windows, powershell, get-eventlog

I'm trying to find the oldest retained Event in the Security Event Log through powershell.

Using the following command: `(Get-EventLog Security | Sort-Object -Property Time -Descending)`

This returns a list which is not sorted in the least.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `Time` isn't a property of events at all. Unfortunately `Sort-Object` doesn't care; `Sort-Object -Property Banana` will give you the same result. Even if  this *did* work, though, it could be very slow if the security log is large. Try `(Get-WinEvent -LogName Security -Oldest -MaxEvents 1).TimeCreated` instead.

Comment: It would be helpful if PowerShell would inform the user that the property does not exist.

Comment: @lit Pretty sure this is pertinent https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a problem with `Get-EventLog`, but caused by the fact that the output of `Get-EventLog` does not have a Porperty `Time`.

Use `Get-Member` to show a list of available properties.

```
Get-EventLog | Get-Member
```

You'll see, that there is a `TimeGenerated` property, which you can use.

```
Get-EventLog Security | Sort-Object -Property TimeGenerated -Descending
```

Furthermore I'd like to add, that that's the default order anyway. But if you want to switch the order, I recommend using `Get-WinEvent` instead, which has a `-Oldest` switch.

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Security -Oldest
```

Answer (score 3):

"Time" is a generated *string* for output purposes not a datetime object so the sorting that is happening isn't chronological but non-existent.

Looking at the DotNetTypes.format.ps1xml you will see that it is using a formatted version of the `TimeGenerated` property.

```
<TableColumnHeader>
    <Label>Time</Label>
    <Width>13</Width>
</TableColumnHeader>
...
...
<PropertyName>TimeGenerated</PropertyName>
<FormatString>{0:MMM} {0:dd} {0:HH}:{0:mm}</FormatString>
```

This is done to have friendlier default output with the caveat of issues like the one you are having.

So, `sort-object` was "working" with a null value hence the lack of visible change.

Either way use the property `TimeGenerated` property instead